# Porting SWP instruction from ARMv4 to ARMv7

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm attempting to port the following piece of code from ARMv4 to ARMv7 since the SWP/SWPB instructions have been deprecated.

```
    swp  a1, a1, [a2]
```

I have had an attempt myself and produced the following code, although I must admit I am unfamiliar with assembler.

```
swapstore1
    ldrex   a3, [a2]
    strex   a4, a3, [a2]
    cmp     a4, #0
    bne     swapstore1

swapstore2
    ldrex   a2, [a1]
    strex   a4, a2, [a1]
    cmp     a4, #0
    bne     swapstore2

swapstore3
    ldrex   a1, [a3]
    strex   a4, a1, [a3]
    cmp     a4, #0
    bne     swapstore3
```

It generates an exception, Data misaligned - code 80000002. I'm guessing it might have something to do with value versus address…

I'm using Microsoft (R) ARM Macro Assembler Version 15.01.50304

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How slow is `swp`?  If it still works at all, it might still be better than replacing it with a loop.  If you want to *gain* performance, you'd probably have to modify the surrounding code to do what it needs to do by efficiently using a different primitive (like `ldrex`/`strex`).  The [examples for using `swp`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/CJHBGBBJ.html) require a loop around it to implement a synchronization primitive.  **If your final code has nested loops to implement an atomic compare-exchange, you're doing it wrong.**

Comment: Peter has a good point - my answer is for the literal "implement atomic exchange with exclusives instead of `swp`" case - if the `swp` is actually just one part of something more complex than a straight atomic exchange operation, then you really want to be rewriting that whole operation in terms of exclusives.

Comment: ldrex/strex is not a direct replacement for swp.   looping is the correct way to use ldrex/strex though.  you may find that swp is not disabled or can be enabled for the core you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so that code goes: load the data pointed to by `a2`, and store it back to the same place, then dereference the data in `a1` as a pointer, load the data from that "address" and store it back to the same place, *then* dereference whatever data you loaded in the first instance as a pointer, load data from that "address" and store it back to the same place. Phew! Even if the bogus addresses *did* happen to be valid, that's a whole lot of not-achieving-very-much.

All you need to do is load the target data, store the replacement data, and retry the whole thing if the exclusive failed. Since the original code has the same source and destination register, you need an extra bit of register-shuffling to avoid trashing the replacement value before you've stored it.

```
swapstore
    ldrex   a3, [a2]
    strex   a4, a1, [a2]
    cmp     a4, #0
    bne     swapstore
    mov     a1, a3
```

Comment: This is true, but there are several caveats with `ldrex/strex`. Generally, the ARM is using the cache to implement a temporary store of data. `strex` is like flushing the cache to *commit* the data (and make other cores aware of it). The OS should do a `clrex` when it flushes the cache and the [a2] memory must be normal cache able memory. Often it is wise to add a `pld/pldw` instruction before hand to insure the data is in the cache. See for example [linux atomic.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h)

Comment: Thanks for that @Notlikethat, on to the next hurdle I go. I'm actually trying to port phoneME to Windows CE 7.